# slow response from kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Spark streaming (Scala) application running in CDH 5.13 consuming messages from Kafka using client 0.10.0. My Kafka cluster contains 3 brokers. Kafka topic is divided into 12 partitions evenly distributed between these 3 brokers. My Spark streaming consumer has 12 executors with 1 core each.
Occasionally, a response is returned from Kafka more than 3 minutes after the request, according to Kafka logs.
What could be the reason for such a delay? Could [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4753) be the root cause and if yes, what is the solution for the problem?

Comment: can you try increasing the no.of cores for spark executor because it's the no.of cores which listens to kafka topic partitions. Since you have 12 cores for executors so all your  executors are assigned to listen to kafka topic. Hence no executor are left to process that consumed data.

Comment: I can try that, but I don't understand how increasing number of cores in executors will help Kafka brokers to return response faster. Please elaborate

Comment: What do you mean "according to Kafka logs"? If Spark is a consumer, then I don't think you'd actively be seeing what Spark is reading from the Kafka server logs

Comment: "according to Kafka logs" means that I print Kafka brokers' logs on TRACE level and see that some requests are served more than 3 minutes after corresponding requests

Comment: does your kafka nodes have enough memory and is skewing of data happening?

Comment: kafka has lots of memory. I am not sure about data skewing